# How to loop through a batch of data to do some operation per sample in Python

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to implement grad-cam approach. Here is my code:

```
for idx, (data, target, meta) in enumerate(tqdm(dataloader_test)):
        print('idx', idx)
        data, target = map(lambda x: x.to(device), (data, target))
        output = model(data)
        output[:,5].sum().backward()
        grads=grad[0].cpu().data.numpy().squeeze()
        fmap=activation[0].cpu().data.numpy().squeeze()
        tmp=grads.reshape([grads.shape[0],-1])
        # Get the mean value of the gradients of every featuremap
        weights=np.mean(tmp,axis=1)
        cam = np.zeros(grads.shape[1:])
        for i,w in enumerate(weights):
            cam += w*fmap[i,:]
        #relu
        cam=(cam>0)*cam
        #cam = np.maximum(cam, 0)
        #print("cam.shape",cam.shape)
        #normalize heatmap
        cam=cam/cam.max()*224
        
        
        for data in range(idx):
            #print('shape data', data.size)
            npic = np.array(torchvision.transforms.ToPILImage()(data).convert('RGB'))
            cam = cv2.resize(cam,(npic.shape[1], npic.shape[0]))
            heatmap=cv2.applyColorMap(np.uint8(cam),cv2.COLORMAP_JET)
            cam_img=npic*0.7+heatmap*0.3
            print(cam_img.shape)
            cv2.imwrite('./visualize/map'+str(count)+'.jpg', cam_img)
            count = count + 1
```

However, I get this error:

```
    raise TypeError(f"pic should be Tensor or ndarray. Got {type(pic)}.")

TypeError: pic should be Tensor or ndarray. Got <class 'int'>.
```

I believe I am looping through each batch the wrong way and not getting the samples I need to do operation over. Any ideas/suggestions for me? Thank you in advance

Comment: What do you expect from `torchvision.transforms.ToPILImage()(0)`?

Comment: @MechanicPig, it convert numpy ndarray to a PIL Image ?

Comment: But the **integer** `0` is not a numpy ndarray. Carefully check your inner for loop, and at this point, `data` will only be integer.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work using this [solution](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-remove-batch-size-in-training-loop-to-perform-certain-operations-on-a-single-image/69020), like this:

`for d, t in zip(data, target):`